# RewriteRule - a.php?a=123 to /b/123

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get Apache to redirect **/a.php?a=123** to **/b/123** (where 123 could be any number between 1 and 9999) but can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^a.php?a=([0-9]+) /b/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a.php$ /c/ [L]
```

With this going to a.php?a=123 results in 404, but going to just a.php works as expected.
I tried escaping the ? (*RewriteRule ^a.php\?a=([0-9]+) /b/$1 [L]*) but it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query string is not part of the URI path that is tested in the `RewriteRule` directive. This can only be tested with a `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^a\.php$ /b/%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^a\.php$ /c/ [L,R]
```

But if you want it the other way (requests of `/b/123` are redirected to `/a.php?a=123`):

```
RewriteRule ^b/([0-9]+)$ a.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you this does look like it should work, but now when I go to either "a.php?a=123" or just "a.php" both are redirecting me to /c/